# How to bundle a js plugin without global namespace clashes

Tags: plugins, javascript, dependency-management

I'm in the process of building a javascript plugin that people will be able to install by simply pasting a script tag into their HTML. At times I may wish to include a third-party library in my plugin, but I want to make sure that my plugin will still work if used on a web site that relies on a different version of this same library. Is there a tool I can use to somehow modify the namespace of my required dependencies so that they don't interfere with any other existing scripts or libraries? I have been researching browserify but it's not immediately clear to me from the docs that it can be used to avoid this problem.

Comment: Don't believe it is possible to entirely remove this problem. Every library needs something in the global namespace, some hide themself better then others, some provide functionality to lessen conflicts (eg. jquery.noConflict()), but in the end it really is up to the library developers to prevent conflicts. If there are conflicts, the only option that i can come up with is to modify that library file yourself, in a best case scenario all you need is to wrap it in a function and give it your own name.

Comment: @Noino, that is a good answer. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.